# Posting Array of JSON data to Express.js Route size limitations

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, node.js, express

I am trying to post (jQuery ajax) an array of JSON objects to my server (Node with Express Routing using BodyParser middleware).  This works fine with small JSON objects but when I attempt to post an JSON object containing an array of coordinate pairs the post fails.  It doesnt even hit my route?

Below is bare bones version of my code.

**JSON object I am trying to post (this is in an array)**

var featureArray = [
                     0: Object
                      geometry: Object
                       coordinates: Array[1]
                       0: Array[368]
                        [0 … 99]
                        [100 … 199]
                        [200 … 299]
                        [300 … 367]
                      ...
                     ]

**Client Side Ajax**

```
insert: function(featureArray,callback){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/insert',
        dataType: '',
        data: {docs:featureArray},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data,textStatus,XMLHttpRequest) {
            callback()
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error Pulling Data")
        }
    });
},
```

**Express Route testRoute.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
router.post('/insert',function(req, res) {
    q = req.body
    console.log(q.docs)
})
module.exports = router
```

**Express App index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var testRoutes = require('./routes/testRoute');

var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '500mb'}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '500mb', extended: true}));

  app.use('/', testRoutes);

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;
    app.set('port', port);
    app.set('ipaddress', ipaddress);
```

Comment: Try to add `app.use(function(req,res,next){ console.log(req.url); next(); });` before and after `app.use(bodyParser....` to log requests so you can see it's gone through the bodyParser

Comment: I did what you suggested, the request does not go through bodyParser when the object in the array is large.  Small objects work fine.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem but I do not fully understand it yet.  The problem is not with bodyParser.  I need to Stringify the array of objects before sending to the server.  Once on the server I can parse back to JSON.  Using this approach everything works but I do not understand why I need to stringify the Array of Objects?

Comment: The $.ajax function should actualy stringify your data internaly so you shouldn't need to do that. When i try to send for example this `data: {docs:[[0,1],[2,3]]},` it works just fine without JSON.stringify. Your featureArray looks a bit wierd to be honest so maybe that is the problem.

Comment: The feature array contains GeoJson http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html created from Ogr2Ogr.  When I Post a simple geojson feature (only a few coordinate pairs) it works as expected.  But complex geojson features (many coordinate pairs) cause the problem.  Using stringify works.